# Differentiate kendo grid previous/next page click vs go to first page/last page click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I know whenever you change the kendo grid page, **pageable-change** event will trigger. But I would like to know how to differentiate between **normal page change click vs go to first/last page click**. I browsed but I couldn't find any. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

This information isn't available in the pageable change event. The best solution is to attach click handlers to the buttons yourself via jQuery.

Comment: Though if you attach event handlers (eg. click) through jquery, initially pageable-change method is called, then only the corresponding click event gets triggered